# php: array_replace_recursive alternative

Tags: php, arrays

I need a solution for `array_replace_recursive`, because my php-version isn't high enough. I want to use this code:

```
$_GET = array_replace_recursive($_GET, array("__amp__"=>"&"));
```

easy, isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

On the PHP docs page for [array_replace_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php), someone posted the following source code to use in place of it:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists('array_replace_recursive'))
{
  function array_replace_recursive($array, $array1)
  {
    function recurse($array, $array1)
    {
      foreach ($array1 as $key => $value)
      {
        // create new key in $array, if it is empty or not an array
        if (!isset($array[$key]) || (isset($array[$key]) && !is_array($array[$key])))
        {
          $array[$key] = array();
        }

        // overwrite the value in the base array
        if (is_array($value))
        {
          $value = recurse($array[$key], $value);
        }
        $array[$key] = $value;
      }
      return $array;
    }

    // handle the arguments, merge one by one
    $args = func_get_args();
    $array = $args[0];
    if (!is_array($array))
    {
      return $array;
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($args); $i++)
    {
      if (is_array($args[$i]))
      {
        $array = recurse($array, $args[$i]);
      }
    }
    return $array;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: When using the function more than once, I get: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare recurse()

Answer (score 1):

The code above by @Justin is ok, save for 2 things:

1. Function is not readily available at start of php execution be cause it is wrapped in if(). [PHP docu](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) says

   > When a function is defined in a conditional manner such as the two examples shown. Its definition must be processed prior to being called.
2. Most importantly; calling the function twice results in fatal error.
   [PHP docu](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) says

   > All functions and classes in PHP have the global scope - they can be called outside a function even if they were defined inside and vice versa.

So I just moved the `recurse` function outside `array_replace_recursive` function and it worked well. I also removed the `if()` condition and renamed it to `array_replace_recursive_b4php53` for fear of future upgradings

Comment: This should be a comment on Justin's answer (because space is limited in a comment, you could post the full message in a link).  Flagged as this is not an answer.